# Convert xml to table using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<DATA>
  <PERSONS>
    <PERSON id="792226" member_id="53534">
      <FNAME>Alfred</FNAME>
      <MNAME> C  </MNAME>
      <LNAME> Kenneth </LNAME>
      <EMAIL> ac1@abc.com </EMAIL>
      <USER_ROLES>
        <ROLE> Abstract </ROLE_NAME>
      </USER_ROLES>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON id="792319" member_id="34526">
      <FNAME> Adam </FNAME>
      <MNAME> F  </MNAME>
      <LNAME> Robert </LNAME>
      <EMAIL> adam@xyz.com </EMAIL>
      <USER_ROLES>
        <ROLE> General</ROLE>
        <ROLE> Reviewer </ROLE>
      </USER_ROLES>
      <AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE>
        <EXPERTISE> Dynamics</EXPERTISE>
        <EXPERTISE> Engineering </EXPERTISE>
        <EXPERTISE> Exploration</EXPERTISE>
      </AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE>
    </PERSON>
 </PERSONS>
</DATA>
```

would like to convert as html table using xslt.  I want to pull only id, member_id, fname, Role and Expertise..Any help would be appreciated.

Updated : I have applied this xslt

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Member ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>ROLE</th>
        <th>Expertise</th>

    </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="DATA/PERSONS/PERSON">
        <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@member_id"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="FNAME"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="USER_ROLES/ROLE"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE/EXPERTISE"/></td>

        </tr>   
        </xsl:for-each>             
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am not sure how to read roles and expertise when it is more than one node. It always shows first node only. if role or expertise are more then one then it should be in a new row   with id, memberid, fname and email.

I would like to display as

[image]

Edited : It should display in new row for each role and expertise. So, For id 792319, it will 5 rows, 2 rows for role and 3 rows for expertise. Little weird, but that is the way they wanted.
Some records may not have no roles and expertise.'

I tried to upload image what I want, but I dont have that much reputation to do that :)

EDIT :

Finally, I have developed this xslt. I got idea from Michael suggestion. Hope this will help others. This xslt read all the records together.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Member ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>ROLE</th>
        <th>Expertise</th>

    </tr>
<xsl:for-each select="DATA/PERSONS/PERSON">

                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="count(USER_ROLES) > 0 or count(AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE) > 0">
                  <xsl:for-each select="USER_ROLES/ROLE" >
                      <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@id"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@member_id"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="../../FNAME"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="../../EMAIL"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="self::ROLE"/></td>
                        <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE/EXPERTISE" >
                      <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@id"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@member_id"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="../../FNAME"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="../../EMAIL"/></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="self::EXPERTISE"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@member_id"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="FNAME"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="EMAIL"/></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                          </xsl:otherwise>      
                 </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:for-each> 
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: You probably want `<PERSONS>` to become your table, `<PERSON>` to become your table row, and id, member_id, fname, user_roles, and areas_of_expertise to become your table data items.

Comment: Sure I can do that. I charge $250/hr for coding services, delivery upon receipt of a full spec. All work is billed in whole hours, minimum time is 5 hours. Alternatively, if you attempt to solve the issue yourself and demonstrate a specific, XSLT assistance is free.

Comment: I have added my xslt which I am using.. Need help for multiple nodes.

Comment: "*if role or expertise are more then one then it should be in a new row with id, memberid, fname and email.*" Is it possible for a PERSON to have zero ROLEs? Or zero EXPERTISEs?

Comment: And how do you want to handle combinations? If a person has 2 roles and 3 areas of expertise - how many rows will that be in total?

Comment: I have updated my xsl, which is little different. If a person have 2 roles and 3 expertise. I think I would display in another rows with their relevant parent id, memberid , fname and email. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I don't think that answers my question.

Comment: Does that mean that role and expertise would never appear in the same row? or only if there is more than one of either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a table like this satisfy your requirements?

[image]

---

### Edit:

It is very simple to produce a table like you want:

[image]

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Member ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>e-Mail</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Expertise</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="DATA/PERSONS/PERSON/USER_ROLES/ROLE | DATA/PERSONS/PERSON/AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE/EXPERTISE">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@member_id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../FNAME"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../EMAIL"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="self::ROLE"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="self::EXPERTISE"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, if a person has neither a role nor an expertise, they will not be included.

---

### Edit 2:

To append the people with no roles nor expertise to the above table, just add another row for each such person. Here's the modified stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Member ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>e-Mail</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Expertise</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="DATA/PERSONS/PERSON/USER_ROLES/ROLE | DATA/PERSONS/PERSON/AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE/EXPERTISE">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@member_id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../FNAME"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../EMAIL"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="self::ROLE"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="self::EXPERTISE"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="DATA/PERSONS/PERSON[not(USER_ROLES) and not(AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE)]">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@member_id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="FNAME"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="EMAIL"/></td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It should display in new row for each role and expertise. So, For id 792319, it will 5 rows, 2 rows for role and 3 rows for expertise. Little weird, but that is the way they wanted.

Comment: @user3377202 Please edit your question and include the exact requested output, **as HTML code**. And you still didn't say if a person can have no role and no expertise.

Comment: This xsl very near to what I wanted.  But as you said I will miss records which dont have roles or expertise. Is there any option to just pull only those records which has NO roles and expertise in this xsl?

Comment: @user3377202 Is it important to keep the original order of the persons? Or can all persons with no roles and no expertise appear at the bottom of the table?

Comment: Even it appears at the bottom of of the table, I would be fine. As I will use it with excel and there I can sort it.

Comment: @user3377202 That's good, because the other option is much more complicated. I have edited my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Michael for this solution.